# How do you prove that $\ln(\frac{x+1}{x}) \leq 1/x$?

Tags: induction, logarithms

How can I go about proving the following?

$$\ln(\frac{x+1}{x}) \leq \frac{1}{x}$$

I've been trying to prove by induction but I'm always getting stuck at the inductive step.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Edit**: I should have said, x can be restricted to just the natural numbers for my purposes.

[image]

Comment: You can't prove this by induction (unless you are restricting to the case where $x$ is a positive integer). Instead, use the fact that $\log(1+t)\le t$ and set $t=1/x$. You can prove that $\log(1+t)\le t$ for all $t$ in a number of ways, e.g. you could use the fact that $\log t = \int_{1}^{t}\frac{1}{y} \, dy$ and considering an upper bound for this integral. Or you could prove it using the inequality $e^t\ge 1+t$, since $\log$ is an increasing function.

Comment: Induction works only if the variable is a natural number (1, 2, 3, ...). Here $x$ is any real number...

Comment: Ah yes, I should have said x is a natural number for my purposes. But a general proof would be even better.

Comment: @Joe Thanks I will try that :)